# Iteratively create a list of URLS from a list and call each for a request

Tags: python, list, loops, url, python-requests

I'm trying to iteratively create urls combining two url variables and a list of unique uuids that need to be added to the url like so `.com/{test_adv_uuid}/`. My current code looks like this:

```
import logging
import requests
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

order_id = 1
order_amount = 10

test_adv_uuid = [
    f'08d79951-1908-4f0f-91aa-40eee5ac0e3f',
    f'30816356-4be2-4def-9793-2913dc7dae82',
    f'40a9420a-3bad-4778-930d-0e3da35355d1',
    f'9c2c4477-21ea-4b90-b72b-db40c8ae9754',
    f'6f0fa70b-4914-458d-8b02-0b6a4475773f',
    f'9614bd9f-afa0-4d93-b709-beb38c99cd66',
]


test_adv_url_body = f'https://listen.whatever.com/{test_adv_uuid}/pixel.png'
test_adv_url_attr = f'https://listen.whatever.com/{test_adv_uuid}/pixel.png?order={order_id}&value={order_amount}'


# look up thread pool stuff for understanding on the download & logging 
THREAD_POOL = 16

session = requests.Session()
session.mount(
    'https://',
    requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(pool_maxsize=THREAD_POOL,
                                  max_retries=3,
                                  pool_block=True)
)

def get(url):
    response = session.get(url)
    logging.info("request was completed in %s seconds [%s]", response.elapsed.total_seconds(), response.url)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        logging.error("request failed, error code %s [%s]", response.status_code, response.url)
    if 500 <= response.status_code < 600:
        # server is overloaded? give it a break
        time.sleep(5)
    return response

def download(urls):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=THREAD_POOL) as executor:
        # wrap in a list() to wait for all requests to complete
        for response in list(executor.map(get, urls)):
            if response.status_code == 200:
                print(response.content)

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(
        format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
        level=logging.INFO,
        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    )
    

    urls = [
        test_adv_url_body,
        test_adv_url_attr
    ]

    download(urls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output I get combines all the uuid items in the list into a single url and looks like:

```
request was completed in 0.286232 seconds [https://listen.whatever.com/%5B'08d79951-1908-4f0f-91aa-40eee5ac0e3f',%20'30816356-4be2-4def-9793-2913dc7dae82',%20'40a9420a-3bad-4778-930d-0e3da35355d1',%20'9c2c4477-21ea-4b90-b72b-db40c8ae9754',%20'6f0fa70b-4914-458d-8b02-0b6a4475773f',%20'9614bd9f-afa0-4d93-b709-beb38c99cd66'%5D/pixel.png?order=1&value=10]
```

How would I go about refactoring this to iteratively make each one of these urls with the dynamic uuids into a separate single request?

Would I iteratively create the urls in a list? or within the request call itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```py
# better style to name your lists with plurals
test_adv_uuids = [
    '08d79951-1908-4f0f-91aa-40eee5ac0e3f',
    '30816356-4be2-4def-9793-2913dc7dae82',
    '40a9420a-3bad-4778-930d-0e3da35355d1',
    '9c2c4477-21ea-4b90-b72b-db40c8ae9754',
    '6f0fa70b-4914-458d-8b02-0b6a4475773f',
    '9614bd9f-afa0-4d93-b709-beb38c99cd66',
]
# use a list comprehension to build the list of urls
test_adv_url_bodies = [f'https://listen.whatever.com/{uuid}/pixel.png' for uuid in test_adv_uuids]
test_adv_url_attrs = [f'https://listen.whatever.com/{test_adv_uuid}/pixel.png?order={order_id}&value={order_amount}' for uuid in test_adv_uuids]
```

and then in your `main()` you'd have

```py
urls = test_adv_url_bodies + test_adv_url_attrs
```

this is technically slightly less efficient than creating the `urls` list in a single `for` loop, rather than using two list comprehensions, so I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader

Comment: Thank you, Ben! I appreciate this and the list comprehension makes a lot of sense. I did this and did a similar but more verbose version of this here: https://replit.com/join/xqmgudlbxb-erilius but ended up with the entire list in the url in both that and this answer which i tried here: https://replit.com/@Erilius/SoulfulTrustingConsulting#main.py - how would i separate these out in the request into single urls?

Comment: Update: I figured out what I was doing wrong - your solution solved this and also helped me nail down some good concepts. Thank you very much!